# How to set loop and behavior for marquee in my custom css?

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a custom marquee for my application.. I want to text animation run only 1 time and stop completely. My code is running repeat after 20s and never stop. I tried replace infinite by "1" ( loop ) and behavior="scroll" but it doesn't work. How to implement it?

**html**

```
<li class="marquee" ng-show="notification_message">
    <a href="#">
       message
    </a
</li>
```

**css**

```
@keyframes left-one {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(100%);
    }
    10% {
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
    40% {
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
    50% {
        transform: translateX(-100%);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateX(-100%);
    }
}

@keyframes left-two {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(100%);
    }
    50% {
        transform: translateX(100%);
    }
    60% {
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
    90% {
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateX(-100%);
    }
}

.marquee a:nth-child(1) {
    animation: left-one 20s ease infinite;
}

.marquee a:nth-child(2) {
    animation: left-two 20s ease infinite;
}
```

Comment: do you have any kind of live code?

Comment: @ha_ryu: do you mean jsfiddle version?

Comment: yep, I tried copying your code but it doesn't work.